# How can I combine a screenshot and two video files with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a folder with video files. Some are `.mov`, some are `.mp4`. As a first step I am converting the `.mov`-files into `.mp4` with:

```bash
while read mov; do
   mp4=$(echo "$mov"|sed -e 's|\.mov$|.mp4|i')
   if [ "$mov" == "$mp4" ]; then
     echo "Failed to generate unique MP4 filename for file $mov"
   fi
   ffmpeg -i "$mov" -c:v libx264 -f mp4 "$mp4"
 done < <(find . -type f -iname '*.mov')
```

This works technically fine.

As a second step I need to merge two video files: the first one is always the same (`intro.mp4` with audio), the second file is the either converted `.mov` or the `.mp4` from the folder (also with audio).
Additionally I need a screenshot of the first frame from the second video, which shall be the very first frame and visible for e.g. half a second (for e.g. youtube-shorts to differentiate the videos).

I create the screenshot with

```bash
ffmpeg -i ${fzbVideo} -ss 1 -vframes 1 ${cover}"_%01d.jpg"
```

which works perfectly fine.

As far as I could I followed the example shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43958438/merge-videos-and-images-using-ffmpeg) and the [documentation of ffmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#filter)
and created a loop for all the videos and the steps of merge screenshot and videos:

```bash
for fzbVideo in *.mp4; do
    # intro should be at the beginning of each video
    intro="intro/fzb-intro.mp4"
    # getting a cover imge
    cover="$(basename ${fzbVideo} .mp4)_cover"
    # naming the output file
    fzbVideoOutput="$(basename ${fzbVideo} .mp4)_output.mp4"
    #   create a cover image from the first frame of the video
    ffmpeg -i ${fzbVideo} -ss 1 -vframes 1 ${cover}"_%01d.jpg"
    # combine the cover image with the intro and the actual video file
    ffmpeg \
-loop 1 -framerate 1 -t 1 -i ${cover}"_1.jpg" \
-i ${intro} \
-i ${fzbVideo} \
-f lavfi -t 0.1 -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 \
-filter_complex '[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0][2:a:0][2:a:0]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1' ${fzbVideoOutput}
done
```

But this creates the error:

```bash
Stream specifier ':a:0' in filtergraph description [0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0][2:a:0][2:a:0]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1 matches no streams.
```

What do I need to change?
Additionally, is there a way to combine the converstion from `.mov` to `.mp4` also in the loop (if necessary)?

---

Meta information: content from the CLI, in case this is important information:

```bash
ffmpeg version 6.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/6.0_1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox --enable-audiotoolbox --enable-neon
  libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100
  libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100
  libswscale      7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100
  libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
  libpostproc    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
Input #0, image2, from 'IMG_5546_cover_1.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:01.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 836 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1080x1920, 1 fps, 1 tbr, 1 tbn
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'intro/fzb-intro.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isommp41mp42
    creation_time   : 2023-11-24T21:59:10.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:00.83, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1247 kb/s
  Stream #1:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 602x1070, 1191 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 600 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-11-24T21:59:10.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #1:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 38 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-11-24T21:59:10.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'IMG_5546.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf60.3.100
  Duration: 00:00:28.37, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3126 kb/s
  Stream #2:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1080x1920, 2989 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc60.3.100 libx264
  Stream #2:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream specifier ':a' in filtergraph description [0:v] [0:a] [1:v] [1:a] [2:v] [2:a] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1 [v] [a] matches no streams.
```

Comment: `[2:v:0][2:a:0]`

Comment: uf, good catch [Баяр Гончикжапов](https://video.stackexchange.com/users/40740/%d0%91%d0%b0%d1%8f%d1%80-%d0%93%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2), but even when I change it, I get the error `Stream specifier ':a:0' in filtergraph description [0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0][2:v:0][2:a:0]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1 matches no streams.`

Comment: change `-loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 1 -i ${cover}"_1.jpg"` and `-f lavfi -t 1 -i anullsrc...` and `[0:v:0][3:a:0]...`

Comment: Thanks. I did all the changes, especially this line `-filter_complex '[0:v:0][3:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0][2:a:0][2:v:0]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1' ${fzbVideoOutput}`, but again I get `Stream specifier ':a:0' in filtergraph description [0:v:0][3:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0][2:a:0][2:v:0]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1 matches no streams.`. Any idea?

Comment: it is strange. it works for me: `... ffmpeg \
-loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 1 -i ${cover}"_1.jpg" \
-t 3 -i ${intro} \
-i ${fzbVideo} \
-f lavfi -t 1 -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 \
-filter_complex '[0:v:0][3:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0][2:v:0][2:a:0]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1' ${fzbVideoOutput}`

Comment: It seems to be due to the format of the different videos? I get the following error 
`Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (mjpeg) -> concat
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> concat
  Stream #1:1 (aac) -> concat
  Stream #2:0 (h264) -> concat
  Stream #2:1 (aac) -> concat
  Stream #3:0 (pcm_u8) -> concat
  concat -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  concat -> Stream #0:1 (aac)
.....`

Comment: part two `Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x151480000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[Parsed_concat_0 @ 0x6000001b80b0] Input link in0:v0 parameters (size 602x1070, SAR 0:1) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (1080x1920, SAR 0:1)
[Parsed_concat_0 @ 0x6000001b80b0] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_concat_0
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #2:0
Conversion failed!`

Comment: `scale` and `pad` before `concat`